# Are previews compatible between Lightroom versions?

Tags: lightroom, storage

Lightroom creates a folder to store previews next to each catalog. This folder is named `<CATALOG> Previews.lrdata` so when a new version of Lightoom Classic is installed and migrates the catalog, it generates previews again for all the same images. This folder takes much more space than the new catalog.

Can the preview folder be shared between version of Lightroom? A link would be required to make it accessible via the names of the original and migrated catalog.

The [Lightroom Classic Catalog FAQ](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/lightroom-classic/kb/catalog-faq-lightroom.html) mentions that certain catalog versions are compatible but I could not find anywhere that has a similar table for previews. Could they be all incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, as you upgrade Lightroom to new versions the previews should be compatible, in my experience. Before CC Lightroom, I even recall using the previews successfully with two versions of Lighroom, as I was installing the new version - the new version generated its own catalog though.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a compatibility list somewhere? Not sure if it will create issues if I just repoint the preview folder of any version to another.

Comment: Did you just create a link or what it an automated process when Lightroom recognized it was possible? Since by default they are stored in different folders.

Comment: I’m confused. Are you experiencing a problem you’re trying to fix, or are you tinkering? You mentioned that when a new version of Lightroom is installed that it migrates the catalog... that never happens for me. It asks to upgrade the catalog, and I save a new version next to the old version. I don’t change its location.

Comment: Everything is working luckily but I am trying to save space. When I installed Lightroom 10, it asked to migrate my old catalog (called `Everything.lrcat`) and created a new one called `Everything10.lrcat`. In the same folder, the previews for the original catalog are in  a subfolder called `Everything Previews.lrdat` but it now created another one called `Everything10 Previews.lrdat`. The older one takes 24GB and the new one 26GB but those are previews for exactly the same images! Well, minus a handful of ones I experimented with in Lightroom 10

Comment: Continuing, I'm hoping to see if I can replace one these folders with a link, so that the same previews can be used. I won't run both versions of Lightroom simultaneously obviously but I want to know if this cause issues/corruption if the previews are repeatedly used by different Lightroom versions. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Weird. Well, if you have no special need to use older software versions, I think you could delete the old previews. You can generate previews at any time if you don’t have them. Menu bar > Library > Previews.

Comment: Good point about deleting them but I guess that means each time I launch Lightroom whose previews I deleted will recreate them... so it will only save space temporarily. If they could be shared it wouldn't be an issue but it's not that bad. I recently added those folder to the 'exclusion list' of my backup scripts to avoid overflowing the backup drive. As you said though, they can be regenerated, so they never needed to be in the backup in the first place.

Comment: I’m not sure what to tell you. Normally they are not regenerated. There isn’t a manual “share” step. They simply are shared.

Comment: OK. On my system, they are simply *not* shared. Maybe it's a Windows 10 thing and you are on  MacOS? It's possible they aren't shared here because they are not compatible. Thanks for checking though!

Comment: I used MacOS with Lightroom v1 when I first started. But I have gone through Win7, 8, 8.1, and now I’m on the latest Win10 20H2.